# How can I make a S/R latch with adjacent inputs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

The Minecraft wiki suggests this:

> [image: The layout]

...with [this](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/images/thumb/c/c1/Redstone_Simulator_Guide.png/414px-Redstone_Simulator_Guide.png) being the key to the diagram.

The way I read it, the set and reset wires run into two blocks. On the opposite side, put a torch on the set side, then run a wire back to the block opposite reset. Above this wire lies another block where a new wire starts and leads to the output.

Obviously this has to be the wrong way to read the diagram, as the reset and output wires are connected to anything.

How can I make a S/R latch with adjacent inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming by adjacent, you mean close enough that your character can reach both at once. Here is a diagram that will do it, basically a mutation of the basic circuit:
[image]

If you need a !Q, then just add an inverter to the top output. If for some reason, you absolutely need a *narrow* version, I'll try to create a more clear diagram of version C, which also has adjacent inputs:
[image]

I'm still working on figuring out how version E (your diagram) works, myself. :)

**Update:** Just found a *much* nicer version at [RS Nor Latch](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/305559-help-rs-nor-latch-e/) by [SH4D0WS1N](http://www.minecraftforum.net/user/172748-sh4d0ws1n/) (his screenshot, my diagram from it):

[image]

Comment: Version C looks close enough, and if I ever needed to do it again I'll try it. Thomas McDonald helped me implement your initial proposal. :)

Comment: @badp, glad it worked, but see the update - I just tested it, it works nicely, and doesn't require *any* in-the-air blocks.

Comment: And I *still* can't figure out how version E works. I'll *assume* the wiki is correct, but I can't determine what powers the middle three air blocks. I suspect I made the bridge wrong, but not sure what the fix is yet.

Comment: Wow, that's a really nice RS-NOR latch, I'll definitely be using that design.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, `design E` on the Minecraft Wiki is a multi-level RS-NOR latch. The image on the wiki is actually a GIF that cycles between 3 different images, but in the question, it only shows the first image (which is why the circuit seems impossible). Here's a [link to the GIF](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/images/7/7d/RS_NOR_Latch_E.gif).

Here is what the circuit looks like when built in-game:

[image: The two buttons are R and S.]

[image: Q and !Q are the rightmost torches in the image.]

Comment: Ah! That explains it... And I even remember seeing somewhere a side-view on the wiki of some circuit, this may be it (and that's what I get for not turning on animated images...). +1, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. It didn't certainly help that the minecraft wiki had only just came back online, with several images missing :)

Comment: Yeah, the forum and the wiki have been pretty on and off lately.

Comment: I actually took screenshots of most of the circuits some months ago, but of course, *those* weren't animated either. :)